# How to build with multiple versions of dependency in java

Tags: java

I want to make my project to support multiple versions of one dependency. And this dependency may have API incompatibility, what's the easiest and best practice to do that ? Is there any way to detect the version at runtime, and control whether to compile the piece of code that using the new feature of the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that the end user could have added any one of a number of versions of a a JAR in their class path and you want to be able to use whatever version they provided.

There is a number of ways of doing this.  You can detect the version if it is build using Maven or similar by looking in the manifest directory.  Another approach is to write a number of adapters, one for each family of versions you are aware of and test which version appears to work.

You can build this in maven by creating a module for each version with an optional dependency on the version this module supports.  You create a class with a unique name e.g. with the version you are supporting in its name.  This will give you N modules with a small number of classes.  You can then create a module which includes all these classes and searches amongst them to find a first which appears to work.  Obviously if you know which versions you are supporting this is better than trail and error, but not always possible.

---

If you want to support multiple version at once, without using custom class loaders you could use a tool like jarjar to rename the package of a number of supported version and provide this in a uber JAR of all supported versions.

Answer (score 0):

you should also consider OSGI. With it you can specify the version of the dependency for each bundle (that is like a single module of your application) and have different bundle depends on different version of the same library.

See also:
http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.6.0.M01/docs/virgo-user-guide/html/ch02s02.html
and
http://www.christianposta.com/blog/?p=247